# Android Studio - Caused by: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: rawproto (Gradle Sync Failed)

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

Error on Android Studio:

> Error:C:\Users\kunal\Desktop\Workspace\StringPatternMatch\build\android-profile\profile-2017-10-06-20-24-56-228.rawproto

Error on idea.log:

> Caused by: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: C:\Users\kunal\Desktop\Workspace\StringPatternMatch\build\android-profile\profile-2017-10-06-20-24-56-228.rawproto

Tried both running Android Studio as Administrator and deleting .gradle folder from the application repository. Still, couldn't fix the problem.

Android Studio Beta works, but the standard version is giving this errors!

[Android Studio Gradle Sync Failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nZPj1.png)

Comment: Make sure that C:\Users\kunal\Desktop\Workspace is accessible(readble/writable) to android studio. Check the directories' permissions and if they exist.

Comment: I did that still no luck! :(

Comment: Default Directory for applications folder works but this doesn't!

Answer (score 9):

Always try:

```
Build -> Clean Project
```

Worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

the reason is definitely the permission of the folder
for centos I had 
chmod -R 777 < folder name>

only the root folder access is not enough all the sub directories should have permission

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue trying to change app version then rebuild apk.

I solved by:

**File > Invalidate Caches and Restart**

Answer (score 0):

I have same ERROR and i fixed by unchecked option read-only in folder properties. You can try uncheck option read-only for folder kunal in window.

Answer (score 0):

Build > Clean Project

can fix my error Try this....

Answer (score 0):

This error happened to me after updating to Dolphin (2021.3.1)

Build -> Clean Project solved it. After cleaning Android Studio did a file system synchronization, and now it is working normally.